# How does Jefry Chandra edit his photos?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, reverse-engineering

seems like a bleach bypass mixed with some custom curves (raising the blacks) but i can't seem to get it right. someone help please!

https://www.facebook.com/JefChan2?fref=ts

Comment: doesn't look bleach bypass to me.  Photos seem very mixed, some contrasty, some more flat.  Why not ask him?

Comment: i tried multiple times, but no luck in response

Comment: Please see [PSA on "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) and add detail to your question accordingly. I know it can be difficult, but without it, questions like this are less likely to get good answers and are very unlikely to be helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Given that most skin features are blown out I can assume that

- He starts with a somewhat bright, somewhat blown out, somewhat
  "milky" picture.
- Then adds adequate contrast to make the black very rich. Like in his
  picture of the blond hair girl with a white sheet.
- Then all that's left is to add a soft "milky effect" there are a
  number of ways to achieve this effect. I personally would use
  SELECTIVE COLOR > chose the BLACK drop down > then slide the BLACK
  SLIDER just a bit to the left. Affecting only the black portions of
  the picture.

Again this is all speculation but I have accomplished this exact effect many times. Also if you wanna go a little further, move the rest of the sliders inside the BLACK drop down to the left and you will see a pretty cool effect happen only to the black areas of your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like he uses presets, something like "Florabella" https://www.facebook.com/FlorabellaActions?fref=ts

Comment: are there any other presets or photoshop actions like this?

Comment: How can you tell the difference between a "preset" and manual adjustment?

Answer (score -1):

Mostly looks like the white and black points are just shifted in a bit to output grey.  Contrast is lowered and shadows to mid are dropped a bit to keep a bit of clear tone.  Pretty much the entire look can be done with curves.

Comment: I think there is also some kind of soft contrast technique applied here as well, which is more than just curves.

Comment: Maybe, but I kind of think that may be a side of the original lighting. They all look like they stayed as vivid and high contrast which helps with keeping strong shadows and mids.